# Trouble with a test class

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, controller

Its a simple enough Controller but for some reason I cannot figure out what the heck to write the test class.

Controller:

```
public with sharing class pairHouseholdController {

    public Id accountID {get;set;}
    public Account a {get;set;}
    //public ID Household {get;set;}



    public pairHouseholdController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        a =  (Account) controller.getRecord();
        accountID = a.Id;
        System.debug('The account record: ' + a);

    }



    public pagereference pairHousehold(){

        Account youthAccount = [Select ID,Household_Account__c, Patient_Category__c From Account where ID =: accountID];

        string household = youthAccount.Household_Account__c;

              If(Household != null){

                    Partner p = new Partner(); 

                    p.AccountToId = accountID; 
                    p.AccountFromId = household; 
                    p.Role = youthAccount.Patient_Category__c; 
                    p.IsPrimary = FALSE; 


                    insert p; 
                }     

        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/'+ accountID);

            pr.setRedirect(true); 

        return pr;
        }

}
```

Test Class, Whats next?

```
@isTest
public class pairHouseholdController_test {

    public static testMethod void pairTestMethod(){



        Id YouthRecordTypeID = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Youth Patient').getRecordTypeId();
        ID HouseholdAccountTypeID = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Household Account').getRecordTypeId();

        Account house = new Account(Name='TEstingCode', RecordTypeID=HouseholdAccountTypeID); 
        insert house; 

        Account patient = new Account(LastName='Tested', FirstName='Imma', RecordTypeID=YouthRecordTypeID, Household_Account__c=house.Id); 
        insert patient; 








    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "construct" an instance of the controller, then call its methods. The constructor is the method with no return type and has the name of the class:

```
public pairHouseholdController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
```

This method wants an ApexPages.StandardController that has the account, so we need to do that first:

```
ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl = new ApexPages.StandardController(patient);
```

Now, we can call that constructor!

```
pairHouseholdController controller = new pairHouseholdController(stdCtrl);
```

Finally, we have a method that we want to test, so we'll call that from the controller's variable:

```
Test.startTest();
PageReference ref = controller.pairHousehold();
```

At this point, our test is done, but we are not. We need to verify that the method worked.

```
Test.stopTest();
Partner partner = [SELECT AccountToId, AccountFromId, Role, IsPrimary FROM Partner];
System.assertEquals(patient.Id, partner.AccountToId);
System.assertEquals(house.Id, partner.AccountFromId);
System.assertEquals(patient.Patient_Category__c, partner.Role);
System.assertEquals(false, partner.IsPrimary);
System.assert(ref.getUrl().contains(house.Id));
```

---

Some other notes...

## testMethod

This is deprecated. Use @isTest instead.

## Auto-Query

Visualforce automatically includes fields you need without the need to query the record again (you just need to include the field in markup).

## Default getter-setter

It appears you're not using them, so don't use them.

## Use Correct Data Types

All Id values are String, but not all String are Id. Using the wrong type in your code can confuse future maintainers of your code (including youself in a year!). Declaring the correct type will solve headaches later.

## Be Descriptive

The variable `a` doesn't mean anything to anyone. You're limited to 40 characters per variable name. Feel free to use more than 1. The only exception I typically permit is `i` or `x` for indices and counters, respectively. Everything else should be more descriptive.

## Use Hints

```
String household;
```

What is this variable? Not only does it have the wrong type, but we don't even know what it means without reading context (e.g. looking at more code). You can make it so much more obvious with fewer keystrokes:

```
Id householdId;
```

We now know this refers to a record by its Id.

Also...

## Avoid Generic Names

`accountId` isn't helpful here, because it doesn't say which account (we're dealing with two!).

### Yes, I Know...

... I said basically the same thing three times. It really is that important.

## Use StandardController View

This makes it more clear what your intent is, and is future-proof.

```
// PageReference pr = new PageReference('/'+ accountID);
PageReference ref = new ApexPages.StandardController(youthAccount).view();
```

## Error Handling?

You should probably check to make sure the DML operation was successful, but if you insist that you don't need it right now, I'll take your word for it.

---

Here's your revised controller:

```
public with sharing class pairHouseholdController {
    Account youthAccount;
    public pairHouseholdController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        youthAccount =  (Account) controller.getRecord();
    }
    public pagereference pairHousehold(){
        Id householdId = youthAccount.Household_Account__c;
        If(HouseholdId != null){
            Partner p = new Partner(
                AccountToId = youthAccount.Id, 
                AccountFromId = householdId, 
                Role = youthAccount.Patient_Category__c,
                IsPrimary = false); 
            insert p; 
        }
        PageReference pr = new ApexPages.StandardController(youthAccount).view();
        pr.setRedirect(true); 
        return pr;
    }

}
```

And your finished test:

```
@isTest
public class pairHouseholdController_test {
    @isTest static void pairTestMethod(){
        Id YouthRecordTypeID = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Youth Patient').getRecordTypeId();
        ID HouseholdAccountTypeID = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Household Account').getRecordTypeId();
        Account house = new Account(Name='TEstingCode', RecordTypeID=HouseholdAccountTypeID); 
        insert house; 
        Account patient = new Account(LastName='Tested', FirstName='Imma', RecordTypeID=YouthRecordTypeID, Household_Account__c=house.Id); 
        insert patient; 
        ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl = new ApexPages.StandardController(patient);
        pairHouseholdController controller = new pairHouseholdController(stdCtrl);
        Test.startTest();
        PageReference ref = controller.pairHousehold();
        Test.stopTest();
        Partner partner = [SELECT AccountToId, AccountFromId, Role, IsPrimary FROM Partner];
        System.assertEquals(patient.Id, partner.AccountToId);
        System.assertEquals(house.Id, partner.AccountFromId);
        System.assertEquals(patient.Patient_Category__c, partner.Role);
        System.assertEquals(false, partner.IsPrimary);
        System.assert(ref.getUrl().contains(patient.Id));
    }
}
```